# Convert PDF to PNG using pdf2image

Tags: python, image, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert a PDF to a PNG file type using pdf2image without using a path. I want to pass a InMemoryUploadedFile into the function for conversion instead of specifying a path to a PDF file. I don't think pdf2image can do this but was wondering if there is another way to do this?

The below code is testing outside of my main project. Trying to figure out how to do it before integrating the function into my project. file = opening from path but is then passed in to act as a InMemoryUploadedFile

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path, convert_from_bytes


file = open(r"PDF\pdf_files\NDB.pdf")
images = convert_from_path(file, poppler_path=r"C:\Python\poppler\poppler-23.07.0\Library\bin")

for pdf in images:
    for i in range(len(pdf)):
        # Save pages as images in the pdf
        images[i].save(f'PDF\image_mods\image_converted_{i+1}.png', 'PNG')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that pdf2image does not directly support converting an InMemoryUploadedFile object. However, you can use the PyPDF2 library to read the PDF content from the InMemoryUploadedFile and then convert it to images using pdf2image. Below is an example of how you can achieve this

```
from io import BytesIO
import PyPDF2
from pdf2image import convert_from_bytes

# Assuming "file" is an InMemoryUploadedFile object containing the PDF content
# Read the PDF content from the InMemoryUploadedFile
pdf_content = file.read()

# Create a BytesIO object to handle the PDF content
pdf_stream = BytesIO(pdf_content)

# Use PyPDF2 to get the number of pages in the PDF (optional step)
pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_stream)
num_pages = pdf_reader.numPages

# Convert the PDF content to images using pdf2image
images = convert_from_bytes(pdf_content, poppler_path=r"C:\Python\poppler\poppler-23.07.0\Library\bin")

# Save each image
for i, pdf in enumerate(images):
    # Save pages as images in the pdf
    pdf.save(f'PDF\image_mods\image_converted_{i + 1}.png', 'PNG')
```

Here, we use BytesIO to create a stream of the PDF content from the InMemoryUploadedFile. Then, we use PyPDF2 to read the PDF content and get the number of pages in the PDF (this step is optional if you don't need the number of pages). Finally, we pass the PDF content (in bytes) to pdf2image's **convert_from_bytes** function to convert it to images, and then save the images as PNG files.

Make sure to install both PyPDF2 and pdf2image libraries if you haven't already

```
pip install PyPDF2
pip install pdf2image
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Is there a way I can convert the ppm image format generated by pdf2image to a PNG format without saving it in to a directory? I want to leave the PNG format as an InMemoryUploadedFile for further manipulation.

Comment: Yes, you can convert the PPM image generated by pdf2image to PNG format without saving it to a directory. You can use the Python Imaging Library (PIL) or its successor, Pillow, to perform this conversion in memory. Pillow allows you to work with images in memory without saving them to disk.